# Laravel Eloquent Chaining many Where(and) with a subsection of Where(or)'s

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a request that returns all users that are a subset of a specific user ID (via connected_id), who are also between one or many age ranges (eg "20-30", "50-60").
The list of ages ranges are presented via another array ($ageRangeTable).
User with ID 5 is ignored.

The user table only contains a date of birth, therefore the age has to be calculated on the fly.

Here's what I have so far, but the exported SQL is ignoring the OR section.
(please note, I'm using "explode" to separate the min and max age for now, as the actual string "x-y" might change soon to something else)

```
 $ageRangeTable = ['20-30','50-60'];
 $result = Users::where('connected_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('id' , '!=',  5)
        ->where(
            function ($query) use ($ageRangeTable) {
                $count = 0;
                foreach($ageRangeTable as $agerange){
                    list($min,$max) = explode( "-", $agerange);
                    if($count == 0){
                        $query->where(`TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, 'dateofbirth', CURDATE() )`, `between`, `{$min} AND {$max}`);
                    }else{
                        $query->orWhere(`TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, 'dateofbirth', CURDATE() )`, `between`, `{$min} AND {$max}`);
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
                return $query;
            }
        );
        //->get(); don't use this yet as we just want to review SQL for now...

        dd($result->toSql());
```

The resulting SQL looks like this:

```
  "select * from `users` where `connected_id` = ? and (`id` != ?)"
```

...which ignores all the "ors". I expected this_

```
  "select * from `users` where `connected_id` = ? and (`id` != ?) and ((`TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, 'dateofbirth', CURDATE() )` BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (`TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, 'dateofbirth', CURDATE() )` BETWEEN ? AND ?))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your quotes are backwards. The backticks should be around the column name, the single quotes around the strings. Single quotes won't expand the variables, you *could* use double quotes, or use [`orWhereBetween`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses), and pass `$min` and `$max` as array. I think you'll also need to pass the first part of the where's as raw with `DB::raw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here:

- Backticks should go around the column names, quotes around the strings
- Single quotes won't expand the min and max variables

There are also a few small tweaks you can use to utilize the QueryBuilder more

- use `whereBetween` for the queries
- Use `DB::raw` for the columns

Your query will then look like this:

```
$result = Users::where('connected_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('id', '!=', 5)
    ->where(
        function($query) use ($ageRangeTable) {
            $count = 0;
            foreach($ageRangeTable as $agerange) {
                [$min, $max] = explode("-", $agerange);
                if($count == 0) {
                    $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, `dateofbirth`, CURDATE() )'), [$min, $max]);
                } else {
                    $query->orWhereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, `dateofbirth`, CURDATE() )'), [$min, $max]);
                }
                $count++;
            }
            return $query;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks - The quotations and backticks were due to me trying something prior to copying the code, I forgot to put it back. I actually forgot whereBetween existed! Can you explain why it needs the DB::raw prefix in the timestampdiff ?

Comment: It's to make sure that Laravel doesn't add backticks around the whole parameter to treat it as a single column name. I don't know the exact rules, but I know it detects `AS` for an alias, but not much else.

Answer (score 1):

try using a raw query - `whereRaw`

```php
$ageRangeTable = ['20-30', '50-60'];

$sqlRaw = [];

foreach ($ageRangeTable as $range) {
    [$min, $max] = explode( '-', $range);

    $sqlRaw[] = sprintf('YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(dateofbirth) DAY)) BETWEEN %d AND %d', $min, $max);
}

$result = Users::query()
    ->where('connected_id', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('id' , '!=',  5)
    ->whereRaw(implode(' AND ', $sqlRaw))
    ->get();
```